# Why do I receive this messeage? = FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: XXXXX

Tags: python, size, os.walk, filenotfounderror

I made a program to walk a Directory Tree, and print out all files over a certain size.
After the programme runs for a while (and prints out the file paths and size for many files), at some point I keep getting the notice...

> FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: XXXXX....

Why does this occur? The file does exist. I manually located it at the prompted path.

```
import os
from pathlib import Path

for foldername, subfolders, files in os.walk(Path.home()):
 for file in files:
  size = os.path.getsize(Path(os.path.abspath(foldername))/Path(file))
  if size >= 100000000:
   print(f'{Path(os.path.abspath(foldername))/Path(file)} has size in bytes: {size}')
```

Comment: check for permissions

Comment: how long is your path? You might be running into [win32api limit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/maximum-file-path-limitation?tabs=cmd)